# Node JS - How can I process UGC to prevent any attack/site vulnerability?

Tags: node.js, security, ugc

We are working on a new feature within Node JS application, where the user can upload any document (pdf, excel, img, etc) and we'll process it in order to show it to other users. Process- I mean to get it's text, generate thumbnail, count pages and more.
While doing it we have a very important point to think of - how can we make sure that no attackers are using this feature to atack our site or even our users?
While the XSS is very poplar point- I'm sure there are other vulnerabilities we should prevent.

I'm sure this subject is a main point of any site/tool that manipulates UGC,
but I was not able to find any standards/cheat-sheats/even a bullets list that describes the process of protect my site while manipulating UGC.

Any reference, link, knowledge share or even an example of another dev language will be appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Web security has a big scope but you're right, XSS is the most popular but it has a few types:

- *Reflected XSS*  - where the malicious script comes from the current HTTP request.
- *Stored XSS*     - where the malicious script comes from the website's database.
- *DOM-based XSS* - where the vulnerability exists in client-side code rather than server-side code

In my opinion, the third one (Dom-based) is the most actual for your app because people can upload some script that will be located in the IMG SRC and when the user loads this image - the malicious script could steal sensitive data such as Cookies/auth tokens, etc.

The most popular protection, in this case, is just to sanitize the special symbols during the "handling process". Sanitize is when you replace the HTML symbols into HTML entities such as: `<` to `&lt;` etc.
You can manually create some Regexp to do it but I'd rather suggest using something like that: [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)   it has many useful features such as:

- Supports HTML, MathML, and SVG
- Supports the usual tag/attribute whitelisting/blacklisting and URL regex whitelisting
- Has special options to sanitize further for certain common types of HTML template metacharacters

and many others

About Web Security whitelists and other possible vulnerabilities.
Please, check these ones, I think they might be  useful for you

1. [Web Security OWASP cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/index.html) - This resource contains a very detailed list with all possible web security rules with examples and solutions
2. [OWASP XSS Filter cheatsheet](https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet) - The document especially for XSS as the most common one

Comment: Thank you very much! your answer is helpful and you opened my eyes into web security!